# Equation Spacing in AMSART

Tags: spacing, equations, amsart

I'm having some small amount of inconsistency with my equation spacing when using the `amsart` class.

I have the following:

```
Paragraph 1 text here.

\begin{equation}
    F_n = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}
\end{equation}

Paragraph 2 text here.
```

At this point, I'm getting a 1-line space between paragraph 1 and the equation, and no space between the equation and paragraph 2.

Further, If I delete the empty line above the equation, the 1-line space before the equation goes away, but no matter how many empty lines I add after the equation, I can't get a 1-line space after it.

EDIT: Adding an explicit linebreak (`\\`) after the equation gives me what looks like 2.5 lines worth of space.

The formatting works as expected when using the standard article format, this is only an issue when using `amsart`.

My questions are:

1. Is this a feature, and not a bug?
2. Is it possible to coerce it into giving me the line space after the equation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not leave a blank line in between display mode equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
Paragraph 1 text here.
%
\begin{equation}
    F_n = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}
\end{equation}
%
Paragraph 2 text here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well that answers the question of uniformity, but that does look ugly in source. Is this (no space before or after equations) the norm? It looks a bit...cluttered.

Comment: Yes, that is the norm as far as I am aware. A blank indicates the start of a new paragraph. Since the equation is not the start of a new paragraph (nor the end of a paragraph) there should not be a blank line before and after.

Comment: A blank line *after* the equation can be used, if the text starts a new paragraph. It's conversely at least disputable style to begin a paragraph with a displayed equation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to your comments above regarding cluttered equations. You can set the space before and after the equations using `setspace` that provides  the command`\setdisplayskipstretch{amount`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setdisplayskipstretch{3}

\begin{document}
Paragraph 1 text here.
%
\begin{equation}
    F_n = F_{n - 1} + F_{n - 2}
\end{equation}
%
Paragraph 2 text here.
\end{document}
```

[image]}